# Xml signatures verifies OK in .NET but fails in Java

Tags: java, .net, xml, digital-signature

I post this in SO because I was not able to find a solution anywhere and spent a lot of time to figure out what the problem was. I hope some developer struggeling with the same problem finds this post in the future :)

C14N-transform seems to be implemented differently in .NET and Java. Two different "standards".

Never manually add the xmlns:xml namespace to your xml-document if a Java client *might* need to verify a contained xml signature. Java seems to strip away xmlns:xml declaration BEFORE verifying the contained signature(!)

[image]

Comment: What library are you using to work with the signatures? Perhaps digidoc4j will work better? It is fully compliant with eIDAS and EU

Comment: Hi @MargusPala. I'm using .NET Framwork (4.7.2). My signatures failed when verified by Java clients but was OK in clients using .NET Framework. I was using the SignedXml API in .NET and the "standard" C14N transform in .NET Framework. My mistake was that I added the xmlns:xml namespace manually to the xml being signed. Java removes that one in its C14N transform implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove (dont add manually!) any xmlns:xml declarations (the red box) if the signature uses C14N transform (the yellow box). Not tested, but this might apply to Executive C14N transforms as well.

- Java (C14N transform) removes any xmlns:xml namespace declarations BEFORE validating the signature
- .NET (C14N transform) keeps the xmlns:xml namespace declaration as-is BEFORE validating the signature

Hence, the xml-hashvalues will be different and Java will report a signature-failure while .NET will report it as OK (if it's OK, of course).

This problem is only verified for Java and .NET but might apply to other signature-API's, too.

Answer (score 2):

Blame this on the XML Canonicalization spec. Section 4.6 (Superflous Namespace Declarations) states firstly:

> Unnecessary namespace declarations are not made in the canonical form.

which implies that the declaration of the XML namespace is dropped, and then says

> The root document element is handled specially since it has no parent
>   element. All namespace declarations in it are retained, except the
>   declaration of an empty default namespace is automatically omitted.

which implies that the declaration of the XML namespace is retained.

Writing specs is hard!

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, Michael. Interesting. I haven't had time to read the whole spec. I probably should :)